# How can i optimize ansible's playbook

Tags: loops, variables, ansible, roles

At this time my playbook looks like this:

```yaml
    - role: co_java
      vars:
        co_java_version: jdk1.6.0_45
    - role: co_java
      vars:
        co_java_version: jdk1.8.0_161
```

Can I iterate with item?
Desiderata:

```yaml
    - role: co_java
      vars:
        co_java_version: {{ item }}
      with_items: 
         - jdk1.6.0_45
         - jdk1.8.0_161
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [Roles doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html)

You cannot do it with the classic way of calling role (like in you above example). But this would be possible with `import_role` and `include_role` available since ansible 2.4.

```yaml
- name: playbook to install java
  hosts: my_hosts

  tasks:
    - name: Include role to install java versions
      include_role:
        name: co_java
      vars:
        co_java_version: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - jdk1.6.0_45
        - jdk1.8.0_161
```

**Meanwhile, it might be easier and even more effective** to modify your role to directly accept a list of jdks to install so the loop takes place directly in the relevant tasks. You could then call it with something like:

```yaml
- name: playbook to install java
  hosts: my_hosts

  roles:
    - role: co_java
      vars:
        co_java_version:
          - jdk1.6.0_45
          - jdk1.8.0_161
```